# Why I can declare if in single lines but not functions in Vimscript?

Tags: vim

This works fine `:if 1 | echo 1 | endif` but this doesn't `function! Bar() | endfunction`

For me it seems perfect valid code, I can do this though

```
:function! Bar() [HIT ENTER]
endfunction
```

Wasn't | suppose to separate instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wasn't | suppose to separate instructions?

That depends upon command. Some take "bar" as separator, other as argument. In particular, `:function` belongs to the second group, while `:endfunction` to the first. See `:h :bar` for detailed info.

Comment: From `:h :bar` _These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be followed by another Vim comand_. Thank you!